# Evaluating each cell in a row based on the cell adjacent to it

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set up a spreadsheet the will color the background of a cell based on the text within another cell. This would have to be set up in a row so that if (for example) B2: contained "done", then A2 would be colored green. Likewise for B3 and A3, B4 and A4, etc. I understand how conditional formatting works, I just don't know what formula to use to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- select A3-A100 (or whatever range, but make note of the top-most row)
- click `format` -> `conditional formatting`
- choose `custom formula is` in the LHS dropdown (last option)
- in the formula box put `=B3="done"`  (this has to be the same row as the topmost cell of the selected range)
- select your format, click `save rules`

Comment: I did't realize it was that easy... Thanks so much !